# Twillio Appointment System Parse

Tags: twilio, parse-server

I am trying to make Twilio integrate with our Parse Server, I know how to send messages to people but what I'm confused about is how you handle a response to the parse sever. I need to use the incoming number to handle (one time only) changing a field in Parse.

How would I handle this on my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When someone sends an SMS message to your Twilio number, [Twilio will make an HTTP request](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request) to a URL that you supply. You can set that URL when you edit one of [your phone numbers](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming). You then need to create an application that can handle that incoming HTTP request.

Parse server is based on Express, as far as I remember. So you can probably follow [this guide which takes you through setting up a server to receive and then reply to an incoming SMS message with Node.js and Express](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/sms/how-to-receive-and-reply-in-node-js).

More specifically to Parse, if you use the example code from the Parse-Server project, you need to do something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var app = express();

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev', // Connection string for your MongoDB database
  cloud: '/home/myApp/cloud/main.js', // Absolute path to your Cloud Code
  appId: 'myAppId',
  masterKey: 'myMasterKey', // Keep this key secret!
  fileKey: 'optionalFileKey',
  serverURL: 'http://localhost:1337/parse' // Don't forget to change to https if needed
});

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
app.use('/parse', api);

// Receive incoming Twilio SMS messages
app.post('/messages', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.Body);
  // do something
  // send an empty response to Twilio
  res.send("<Response />");
});

app.listen(1337, function() {
  console.log('parse-server-example running on port 1337.');
});
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Yes that does help a lot! Would it be easier to call a cloud function or just actually do the things I need to do inside of the same spot that I declare the app.post? Just thinking for organization and clarity point.

I would then basically just use the JavaScript SDK for parse to perform what I need to perform right?

Comment: Oh, erm, I'm not sure how to best lay out a Parse app, if you want to maintain that as a cloud function then that can work, or you can just use the plain Express method. It depends on how you organise the rest of your code.